# Save results with response data in JMeter without rerunning the test

Tags: jmeter

How can I save the results of a test run with the response data but without [needing to re-run the test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter/) in JMeter?

I ran a test for 1 hour and I can see in the Test Results that the response data is there, however the csv file is missing them. Is there a way to save the response data of the existing test run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way of getting this. Also be aware that if you want to save the data you're seeing in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener be aware that it saves only last 500 sample results (unless you [modified `view.results.tree.max_results` property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)).

1. So if you're running your test in GUI mode and have View Results Tree listener enabled - you can click each result and save its response somewhere
2. If you don't have the listener enabled (or you run your test in non-GUI mode) you can take a [heap dump](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-capture-java-heap-dumps-7-options) and then extract the response data from it (for example using OQL Console of the [Java Visual VM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) you can execute `heap.findClass("org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult")` query)

   [image]

   switch to Instance View:

   [image]

   and for each instance there will be `responseData`

   [image]